# unable to pass recordId to screen flow on community site

Tags: experience-cloud, screen-flow

I created a `Lightning Web Component` which is a custom compact layout to use on the community. The component allows me to show buttons with conditions since dynamic forms are not available on the `Experience Cloud`.

To add action to the compact layout. I add a record on my custom metadata type that contains the url to the screen flow :

[image: custom metadata record]

I added `recordId` variable to the flow :

[image]

and I have a screen to display the Id :
[image]

When I click on the button the flow appears but it's unable to get current record Id :

[image]

[image]

Comment: what type of licenses are your community users using as opportunity is only visible towards partner community users https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.admin_communities_license_access_mfg.htm&type=5

Comment: @Gilhil we are using Partner Community license.

Comment: As I understand that You have an LWC component ( it is mounted into one of the Digital Experience Site Page). And This LWC has some fields and buttons and this component screen is dynamic according to some rules. This LWC retrieve field and button ( actions ) from Custom Meta Data. But flow button is not working as expected. Flow link is redirected with record id but flow screen is not populated the record id data. To identify issue I need to check more to understand the problems. So you may write some console log statement and check the url is correct or not. Some time URL can be contain two

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was the URL format. The URL format on community flow pages accepts arguments in the following form :

```
/flow/test_compact_layout?flowArguments=[{"label":"recordId","dataType":"String","value":"{Id}"}]
```

As it's explained in the [documentation](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=release-notes.rn_networks_flow_urls.htm&release=220&type=5).